# Does Protractor come with Jasmine 2.x yet?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I was reviewing Protractor website and saw [this paragraph](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/frameworks#using-jasmine) mention that Protractor development is in the process of upgrading to Jasmien 2.0.

> *Currently, Jasmine Versions 1.3 and 2.0 are supported. Jasmine 1.3 is the default test framework and is available for use when you install Protractor. However, we're in the process of upgrading to Jasmine 2.0, and will deprecate support for 1.3 in the future.*

After digging further into [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L267-L270), it looks like Jasmine 2.0 is already supported. Does their website need to be revised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation page can probably be improved to avoid confusion. Most importantly, it points out that nowadays (since [`protractor` 1.6.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-6)), *both `jasmine 1.x` and `jasmine 2.x` are supported* and you can choose which one to use.

There is a [specific setting](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/jasmine-upgrade) that controls the behavior:

```
framework: "jasmine"  // or "jasmine2" for jasmine 2.x
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, do you know if Protractor installs a 2.x version of Jasmine? If so, which version do they install?

I'm looking to see if I need to install Jasmine with npm, because I'll just get the latest which is 2.3 as of today.

Comment: @TonyKlotz when you install protractor jasminewd2 gets installed automatically which is an adapter between webdriverjs and jasmine. Ans jasminewd2 is updated to keep in sync with jasmine 2.x. Even if you install jasmine with npm protractor wont make use of it.

Comment: @GirishSortur thanks for the information! I appreciate it